# Get property from object in array

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am having trouble getting an `NSString` property from an array.  I have an `NSArray` composed of an object called `JSMessage`.  Inside of this object is a string called `sender` I am trying to retrieve.  At the moment, I am only trying to print it to the log.  Here is the code I am trying:

```
NSLog(@"%@",[[self.messages [objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]].sender ]);
```

I get an error about my brackets and another one telling me `objectAtIndex` is an undeclared identifier.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

It should be `[self.messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]`

From here you can see the object in a certain index.

To get the JSMessage object:

```
JSMessage *jSMessageObj = [self.messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, think about it. Your code contains the phrase `[objectAtIndex`. But a method name can *never* be the first thing in square brackets. The first thing in square brackets must be the receiver to which the message is being sent.

For example, you say `[myString lowercaseString]`. You don't say `[lowercaseString]`. But that is what you are saying.

Comment: [self.messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row].sender - is this closer to what I want?  It's not picking up the `sender` property.  Do I have to set it equal to a JSMessage object first and go from there?

Comment: The `sender` property thing is a different issue! `objectAtIndex:` returns an `id`, and an `id` has no `sender` property. You can assign or cast to a JSMessage; alternatively, use the method rather than the property, `[[self.messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] sender]`.

Comment: Yup I just realized this.  Late night coding, heh.

Comment: I discuss the dot-notation-with-`id` issue here (see the fifth paragraph, the one in parentheses): http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch05.html#_properties

Answer (score 0):

Besides removing all of the extra brackets, you can also do the following:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [self.messages[indexPath.row] sender]);
```

This uses the modern syntax for accessing elements from an `NSArray`. And since the array access returns an object of type `id`, you can't directly access the object's property using property syntax. You need to call the getter method as I show above.